# Python Requests POST - 408 timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests, geocoding

I'm trying to do Geocoding of addresses in Python using the Batch API at HERE.com (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/batch_geocoding/batch-geocode-addresses)

```
url = 'https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs?app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&indelim=%7C&outdelim=%7C&action=run&outcols=displayLatitude%2CdisplayLongitude%2ClocationLabel&outputcombined=true'.format(APP_ID=appId, APP_CODE=appCode)

headers = {'content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}

payload = open('payload_sm.txt')

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Which gives me:

### 408 Request Timeout

## Request Timeout

Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.

---

I'm not positive the txt file is formatted correctly. Visually, it looks like their sample input. I think I would get a "**400 Bad Request**" instead if that were the problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "Can anyone see a mistake in my code?"